# how to solve the null error in order to be successful to detect the collisions?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, collision-detection, intersection

I want to implement a game like angry birds using swing, but in a simple way.So whenever user clicks shoot button, a ball will be thrown toward the three squares. And if they have intersection, a "collision" message should be printed out.
Here are my classes:

```
  import javax.swing.*;

public class ProjectileShooterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               ProjectileShooterPanel.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;


class ProjectileShooterPanel extends JPanel {

    static Rectangle gerd;
    static Rectangle hadaf1;
    static Rectangle hadaf2;
    static Rectangle hadaf3;

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600, 600);
        final ProjectileShooter projectileShooter = new ProjectileShooter();
        ProjectileShooterPanel projectileShooterPanel = new ProjectileShooterPanel(
                projectileShooter);
        projectileShooter.setPaintingComponent(projectileShooterPanel);
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("Angle"));
        final JSlider angleSlider = new JSlider(0, 90, 45);
        controlPanel.add(angleSlider);
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("Power"));
        final JSlider powerSlider = new JSlider(0, 100, 50);
        controlPanel.add(powerSlider);
        JButton shootButton = new JButton("Shoot");
        shootButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int angleDeg = angleSlider.getValue();
                int power = powerSlider.getValue();
                projectileShooter.setAngle(Math.toRadians(angleDeg));
                projectileShooter.setPower(power);
                projectileShooter.shoot(gerd,hadaf1,hadaf2,hadaf3);
            }
        });
        controlPanel.add(shootButton);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.getContentPane().add(projectileShooterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
private final ProjectileShooter projectileShooter;

public ProjectileShooterPanel(ProjectileShooter projectileShooter) {
        this.projectileShooter = projectileShooter;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;
Projectile projectile = projectileShooter.getProjectile();
if (projectile != null) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
Point2D position = projectile.getPosition();
int x = (int) position.getX();
int y = getHeight() - (int) position.getY();
gerd = new Rectangle(x - 01, y - 10, 20, 20);
g.draw(gerd);
// g.fillOval(x-01, y-10, 20, 20);
}
        hadaf1 = new Rectangle(450, 450, 50, 50);
hadaf2 = new Rectangle(500, 450, 50, 50);
hadaf3 = new Rectangle(475, 400, 50, 50);
g.draw(hadaf1);
g.draw(hadaf2);
g.draw(hadaf3);


        }
        }
```

and:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

class ProjectileShooter {
    private double angleRad = Math.toRadians(45);
    private double power = 50;
    private Projectile projectile;
    private JComponent paintingComponent;

    void setPaintingComponent(JComponent paintingComponent) {
        this.paintingComponent = paintingComponent;
    }

    void setAngle(double angleRad) {
        this.angleRad = angleRad;
    }

    void setPower(double power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    void shoot(Rectangle test, Rectangle test1, Rectangle test2, Rectangle test3) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                executeShot();
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
          if (test3.intersects(test))
          {System.out.println("collision");}

    }

    private void executeShot() {
        if (projectile != null) {
            return;
        }
        projectile = new Projectile();
        Point2D velocity = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angleRad).transform(
                new Point2D.Double(1, 0), null);
        velocity.setLocation(velocity.getX() * power * 0.5, velocity.getY() * power * 0.5);
        projectile.setVelocity(velocity);
        long prevTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (projectile.getPosition().getY() >= 0) {
            long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            double dt = 3 * (currentTime - prevTime) / 1e8;
            projectile.performTimeStep(dt);
            prevTime = currentTime;
            paintingComponent.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
        }
        projectile = null;
        paintingComponent.repaint();


    }

    Projectile getProjectile() {
        return projectile;
    }
}
```

and:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

class Projectile {
    private final Point2D ACCELERATION = new Point2D.Double(0, -9.81 * 0.1);
    private final Point2D position = new Point2D.Double();
    private final Point2D velocity = new Point2D.Double();

    public Point2D getPosition() {
        return new Point2D.Double(position.getX(), position.getY());
    }

    public void setPosition(Point2D point) {
        position.setLocation(point);
    }

    public void setVelocity(Point2D point) {
        velocity.setLocation(point);
    }

    void performTimeStep(double dt) {
        scaleAddAssign(velocity, dt, ACCELERATION);
        scaleAddAssign(position, dt, velocity);
    }

    private static void scaleAddAssign(Point2D result, double factor, Point2D addend) {
        double x = result.getX() + factor * addend.getX();
        double y = result.getY() + factor * addend.getY();
        result.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

but when I execute it, it does not declare collisions and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Rectangle.intersects(Rectangle.java:786)
    at ProjectileShooter.shoot(ProjectileShooter.java:34)
    at ProjectileShooterPanel$1.actionPerformed(ProjectileShooterPanel.java:38)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

How should I solve it? please me me answers, I am new in java.
thanks

Comment: Have you initialised `gerd` variable before using it in `shoot()` method?

Comment: It looks like it was initialized in paintComponent(), but I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: I am not sure, it is intialised in paintComponent class, but not sure if it is before method shoot or not?

Comment: May I ask if you are shooting a moving ball into a stationary one? I think that you only initialize "projectile" if you shoot the ball (in ProjectileShooter.executeShot())

Comment: I'm guessing that your problem is that projectile is null when you call getProjectile(), which causes `gerd` to be null.

Comment: Have you tried running in a Debugger? Placing a breakpoint right before the line where you get the Exception will tell you which of you variables are null, at least.

Answer (score 0):

In class ProjectileShooterPanel all references gerd,hadaf1,hadaf2,hadaf3 is null.

```
class ProjectileShooterPanel extends JPanel {
    static Rectangle gerd;
    static Rectangle hadaf1;
    static Rectangle hadaf2;
    static Rectangle hadaf3;
```

You should initialised it before pass to shoot method

```
projectileShooter.shoot(gerd,hadaf1,hadaf2,hadaf3);
```

Comment: Note: this is done in paintComponent(). I'm not sure if you're calling this elsewhere OP.

Answer (score 0):

You perform the intersects - check on the Event-Thread that executes `actionPerformed` on your `shootButton` - `ActionListener`. I guess what you really want to do is to perform this check repeatedly, for example on every iteration of your movement loop, or perhaps on every repaint.

I suggest you move that check to a place where you know that the Rectangles are initialsized - e.g. in your `paintComponent`.

You should also really look into synchronisation and locking. Getting Mutlithreading right is one of the herder toppics in programming, but also one of the most powerful tools in our hands.